# FullCalendar invalid event display

Tags: fullcalendar

I am experiencing a strange bug when creating events in week view using a customized resourceTimeGridWeek. Occasionally, the end time of a successfully created event does not align with the time slots. For example, an event that ends at noon may have its bottom border aligned with 11:45. This behavior can be seen in the screenshot provided:
[image]

[image]

Anyone experienced this? I'm using

"@fullcalendar/react": "^5.11.1"
"@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid": "^5.11.0"

Comment: you could change [slotDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration) to 15 minutes, then your problem is probably solved ?

Comment: I tried it, and it isn't solving the issue, the event is still sometimes misaligned with the time slots. Not to mention that I would prefer to actually address the root cause

Comment: You could file a bug report, when you think it is a bug here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/new/choose

Comment: @Luuk I made some progress but still have not completely identified the issue. What I've found out is that in these cases, the duration of the of event is actually read from defaultTimedEventDuration (which is 1 hour by default). Meaning if an event is misaligned by 15min, and I pass  defaultTimedEventDuration="03:00", it will now be misaligned by 2 hours and 15 mins. No idea why it uses defaultTimedEventDuration in these cases

Comment: Found it, startTime was after endTime, take a look at the day.

Comment: It should issue, at least, a warning when you send an end time that is before starttime, so? File a bug ?